# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s}{(s + 1)^2 - 4}$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

> I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \dfrac{s}{(s + 1)^2 - 4} \right\}$. My textbook says that the solution is $e^{-t} \cosh(2t) - \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-t}\sinh(t)$.

But I think this is incorrect. If this is incorrect, can someone please help me find the correct one?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just do partial fraction decomposition. $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ \frac{1}{s+a}\} = e^{-at}$ for $t>0$.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Partial fraction decomposition of $\dfrac{s}{(s + 1)^2 - 4}$ ?

Comment: Yes, do partial fraction decomposition of that.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin ok thanks.

Comment: Yes, your book is wrong. Expression written in book is made up of 4 different exponential functions, but our inverse is made out of only 2

Comment: I think it's just a minor typo - the answer you get through partial fraction decomposition is equivalent to $e^{-t} \cosh(2t) - \frac{1}{2} e^{-t} \sinh(2t)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{s}{(s+1)^2-2^2} = \frac{s}{(s-1)(s+3)} = \frac{1}{4(s-1)}+\frac{3}{4(s+3)},$$
and $$\mathcal{L}(e^{at}) = \frac{1}{s-a}.$$

---

For the textbook solution, it is useful to write the given fraction as
$$\frac{s}{(s+1)^2-2^2} = \frac{s+1-1}{(s+1)^2-2^2} = \frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2-2^2} -  \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{(s+1)^2-2^2},$$
and note that
$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-at}\cosh(bt)) = \frac{s+a}{(s+a)^2-b^2},$$
and
$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-at}\sinh(bt)) = \frac{b}{(s+a)^2-b^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \dfrac{s}{(s + 1)^2 - 4} \right\}$$

$$=\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \dfrac{s+1}{(s + 1)^2 - 4} \right\}-\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \dfrac{1}{(s + 1)^2 - 4} \right\}$$

$$=e^{-t} \cosh(2t) - \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-t}\sinh(2t)$$

Comment: Are you sure your last part $\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-t}\sinh(t)$ is correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. The 1/2 takes care of the missing 2 in the  numerator

Comment: It should be $\sinh(2t)$ instead of $\sinh(t)$.

Comment: Oh yes. You are correct. I fixed it in my answer, thanks